# How can I do bumped textures in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, shaders

I was trying to follow this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i7aLH7XDhZ0

But I noticed those fields only show up in Blender Render. How can I achieve this same result in the Cycles Engine?

Comment: I'm sorry. You're right. I'm trying to get a sort of Dinossaur/dragon skin texture by using the Voronoi Crackles. And I want to know how I can achieve that by using the method the video showed in Cycles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take the factor from your texture into a Vector/Bump node, then take the normal from that node into the normal input on your shaders.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. But how would I apply the Voronoi Crackle effect onto it?

Comment: http://www.instructables.com/id/Hand-Drawn-Voronoi-Diagrams/?ALLSTEPS